# Listening for package change events of certain package

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a pro key application package for my application, and I would like to set up a BroadcastReceiver to receive intents when the pro key package is added or updated. Here's my code:

```
<receiver android:name=".Receiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED" />
        <data android:scheme="package" android:path="com.test.key"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

The code starts up the receiver on every app I install or update the com.test.key app, but it fires for every other apps as well. How can I listen for package updates for com.test.key only?

**I know how to do it in the Receiver.java (intent.getData().getSchemeSpecificPart()). I'm looking for a way to do the filtering in the Android Manifest, so the broadcast doesn't get fired every time user installs an app.**

Comment: I haven't recently examined an `Intent` that was broadcast with either of these actions. What does the data `Uri` that you receive look like? The only examples I see of watching for these broadcasts do not try to filter on more than the scheme.

Comment: I examined the data passed to the BroadcastReceiver and I'm able to get the exact package name of the app that was installed like this: `intent.getData().getSchemeSpecificPart()` (in this case com.test.key). While someone could say the case is closed, for me it seems unnecessary to run my code every time an app is installed and use an if statement to determine if the updated package was my app. I would like to only listen for intents for my package. By the way, the original receiver code in my question was copied from Titanium Backup manifest file.

Comment: @CommonsWare I forgot to notify you of my comment.

Comment: @liro: Well `getSchemeSpecificPart()` doesn't really match any of the `<data>` criteria. What happens if you call `getHost()`? BTW, you can't have `android:path` without `android:host`, anyway, so you might consider trying `android:host="com.test.key"` (and removing your `android:path`) and seeing if that helps.

Comment: `getSchemeSpecificPart()` returns the value I want to get(com.test.key), `getHost()` returns null. When adding `android:host="com.test.key"` the receiver doesn't get a broadcast.

Comment: @liro: Then you're not going to be able to filter by package, in all likelihood.

Comment: @CommonsWare Does it slow anything / use more memory if I just get all the package_added events and use if statement to determine if it was the key package that was installed compared to having no receiver for the event? If I can't filter by package, that means Titanium Backup can't filter by packages either, which means TB is using the same thing then.

Comment: @liro: While you will briefly consume some CPU/RAM, bear in mind that users simply don't install or update packages all that often. It's not like it's every 3 minutes or something. I wouldn't worry about the performance implications of being executed for every package.

Comment: @CommonsWare I still don't like the idea. It's pretty unnecessary to check the package name every time. I'll consider just making the app without a receiver and have the user press "I have the pro key" button to validate their key / do a check if the package exists onCreate. I still wonder what would happen if all currently installed apps checked for the package name every time the user installed or updated a package. I'll put a bounty on this question if somebody comes up with a hack.